# Eclipse: how to search string, but not in comments

Tags: regex, eclipse

How to search for "*" (Multiplication operator) in source code?

Not the asterisc character (in comments, etc...). Just the operator *!

```
/** foo method */    // <- this should not be in search results 
public int foo(int i, int j)
{      
    /* compute the values */ // <- this should not be in search results 
    return i * j;            // <- this should be in search results 
}
```

Comment: Do you use eclipse's multiline comments like `/*[newline]* blah[newline]*/` ?

Comment: Ok, then t might be complicated. Try searching for " * ".

Comment: Is there a mix of comments that start with `/**` and ones that start `/*`.  Both are valid, and both end with `*/`.  Also, do you always end with `*/` or is there variance there too?

Comment: `/**` ones are javadoc comments. Both end with `*/`. I don't know if somebody uses `**/`.

Comment: @Pietu1998 Some, er, _graphic artists_ start and end comments with `/***********` resp `*********/`and even paint boxes. Biggest waste of productivity ever as you either have to change and repaint every time you change the comment or thus prevent people from changing comments because of the needed layout effort. An imbecility nearly equaled by "align identifiers in columns".

Comment: I think it can be done even with the fun "graphic artists".  I am taking a stab at it now.  I think it def. has to be done with Regex, and not simply with file search (see @His) response about not being able to File Search inside comments and such.

Comment: I am not sure if I got you correctly or if I wasn't clear in my answer. The Regex have to be applied within (Eclipse's!) file search, but not within Eclipse's Java search dialog. But Regex definitely can't give you a 100% solution (because Java is not a regular language), but depending on the source it might give you a viable solution. But that can't be told without knowing the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. Eclipse file search does not know about comments so you can't easily exclude results in comments. The (semantic) Java search does not allow to search for operators, only types, methods and such (a weakness of the search dialog to allow the search for texts that are nor legal identifiers - it looks like a text search but it isn't).

So you only can help yourself with file search with regex, which might work in most of your cases but will not be 100% correct and depending on the style of the comments and string literals in your source might fail.

Write a regex that searches for all * except after "//", "/*" or ("*" at the beginning of a line or only after whitespaces). Especially the last case may be problematic depending on where you break long mathematical terms. If you leave the operator as last symbol on the previous line it is no problem, if it is the first symbol at the new line it is. In that case, depending on how urgent the search is, you might think of reformatting your sources for the search. Reformatting everything is quite easy in Eclipse.

Comment: OK. I was expecting more from Eclipse search engine... There's "Java Search" tab, that I supose it has some "intelligence", because it can search in different types of objects (like methods, package, field, etc...).  This regex did the trick: ^(?!\s*(//|\*|/\*)).*\*

Answer (score 1):

This regex did the trick:

```
^(?!\s*(//|\*|/\*)).*\*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search through Eclipse using a regex search, and I have figured out the regex to use.  You can see an example [here](http://rubular.com/r/wqBDFiku7d).  The example has a bunch of different kinds of comment blocks I used for testing the regex.

`(?mx)(?<![\/\*+\n])\*+(?![\n\*+\/])`

It involves a combination of 3 pieces:

1. Negative look behind on `/` followed by 1 or more `*`, this indicates the start of the comment.
2. The actual match we are looking for `\*+`, or "one or more" `*`
3. The Negative look ahead for the end of the comment block `*` in any number followed by a `/`.

The `mx` at the beginning tells the regex to look over multiple lines.  So when it fires, it is looking for the middle pattern `\*+` that is NOT preceded by any starting comment, and NOT ended with any ending comment (regardless of however many `*`s are used).

This can be changed to find any pattern that is not contained within a Java comment, no matter how large or crazy the "art" of the comment is.  By using `(?mx)(?<![\/\*+\n])PATTERN_GOES_HERE(?![\n\*+\/])` and replacing `PATTERN_GOES_HERE` with the pattern to search for not being contained in a comment.  That will let you insert any crazy pattern you need, where the important part of it not being contained inside a comment is handled by the negative look behinds/aheads.